# Mobx decorators for React Native app

Tags: react-native, ecmascript-6, babeljs, mobx

I've created a simple app (using create-react-native-app) to learn how to use Mobx together with React in an iOS app. This is my code:

src/TodoStore.js

```
import React from "react"
import { observable } from "mobx"

class TodoStore {
  @observable list = ["one", "two"]
  @observable filter = ""

  addListItem(item) {
    this.list.push("drei")
  }
}

export default TodoStore
```

src/Container.js

```
import React from "react"
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { observer } from "mobx-react"

@observer
export default class Container extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text>Open up App.js to start working on your app!</Text>
      </View>
    )
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import Container from "./src/Container"
import store from "./src/TodoStore"

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Container />
    );
  }
}
```

.babelrc

```
{
  "presets": ["babel-preset-expo"],
  "env": {
    "development": {
      "plugins": [
        "transform-decorators-legacy",
        "transform-class-properties",
        "transform-react-jsx-source",
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I've run `yarn add --dev babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy`.

The iOS simulator shows me an error (I'll append the image at the bottom).

Now if I comment out these two lines in `src/TodoStore.js`:

```
  @observable list = ["one", "two"]
  @observable filter = ""
```

then error disappears. As I'm quite new to Babel and ES6 I'm not sure if I'm missing a Babel plugin or what else could be wrong. `decorator is not a function` is for sure supposed to tell me something but I'm not sure what leads to this message. Google, similar questions on SO and tutorials couldn't help me. Thanks for taking a look.

[image: simulator screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

You need to import `@observer` from `mobx-react/native`